Inheriting template with t-name not working
I am new to Odoo. I am trying to add a new button in the oe-chatter topbar in odoo 17.0
I found chatter.xml (https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/17.0/addons/mail/static/src/core/web/chatter.xml) that contains the elements of the top bar. I'm currently struggling but do not know how to fix it. The chatter.xml only contains t-name but whenever I used t-inherit or t-inherit-mode, it gives me the error mentioned below.
Here is my xml code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <t t-inherit="mail.Chatter" t-inherit-mode="extension">
        <xpath expr="//*[contains(@class, 'o-mail-Chatter-activity')]" position="after">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary text-nowrap me-2">             
                    <span>Show messages</span>
            </button>
        </xpath>
    </t>
</odoo>

It gives me an error "AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: t, line 3". I do not know what is wrong. Please help. Thanks a lot.

The error could be caused by the t-name that you have forgotten in your xml-code, and you should add a js file to handle the click on the button and a python file to change the message content accordingly:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates>
   <t t-name="mycustom.Chatter" t-inherit="mail.Chatter"
      t-inherit-mode="extension">
       <xpath expr="//*[contains(@class, 'o-mail-Chatter-activity')]" position="after">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary text-nowrap me-2" t-on-click="showMessages">             
                    <span>Show messages</span>
            </button>
        </xpath>
  </t>
</templates>

Js file to handle the click on the button:
/** @odoo-module **/
import { Chatter } from "@mail/chatter/web_portal/chatter";
import { patch } from "@web/core/utils/patch";
patch(Chatter.prototype, {
   async showMessages() {
        await this.env.services.action.doActionButton({
           type: "object",
           resModel: this.props.threadModel, 
           resId: this.props.threadId,        
           name: "action_show_messages", 
       });
   },
});

Python file to change the message content accordingly:
def action_show_messages(self):
       for record in self:
           record.important = True
           record.message_post(body="your additional messages...")
       return {
           'type': 'ir.actions.client',
           'tag': 'reload',
       }

A tutorial about this topic here:
https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-the-chatter-in-odoo-18
